# Sending a sorted table from pandas dataframe to frontend?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I'm doing some calculations on financial data and my raw json looks something like this:

```
[
  {
    "company": "Apple Inc",
    "earnings_yield": "0.032220032460810885",
    "roic": "0.18313585674458502"
  },
  {
    "company": "Microsoft Corporation",
    "earnings_yield": "0.0360941393518613",
    "roic": "0.1955875358727057"
  }
]
```

I run the json through a pandas Dataframe where I rank them:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(companies)
df['roic_rank'] = df['roic'].rank()
df['ey_rank'] = df['earnings_yield'].rank()
df['sum_rank'] = df['ey_rank'] + df['roic_rank'].rank()
```

Which returns:

```
                 company  earnings_yield    roic  roic_rank  ey_rank  sum_rank
0              Apple Inc          0.0322  0.1831        1.0      1.0       2.0
1  Microsoft Corporation          0.0361  0.1956        2.0      2.0       4.0
```

What would be a good way of returning this sorted table back to the frontend so I can display it nicely in a dropdown with ascending/descending order (on `sum_rank`)

If I just do `df.to_json()`, all my work with pandas is thrown out the window, as the json is returned like this:

```
{
  "company": {
    "0": "Apple Inc",
    "1": "Microsoft Corporation"
  },
  "earnings_yield": {
    "0": 0.0322200325,
    "1": 0.0360941394
  },
  "roic": {
    "0": 0.1831358567,
    "1": 0.1955875359
  },
  "roic_rank": {
    "0": 1,
    "1": 2
  },
  "ey_rank": {
    "0": 1,
    "1": 2
  },
  "sum_rank": {
    "0": 2,
    "1": 4
  }
}
```

Comment: what is the expected json output?

Comment: Maybe `df.to_dict("records")`?

Comment: some sorted json with an array of objects where the first element is the index with the lowest 'sum_rank'

Answer (score 1):

You can try groupby

```
json = df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x.to_dict(orient='records'))
json = json.to_json()
```

Output will be something like this:

```
'{"0":{"company":{"0":"Apple Inc"},"earnings_yield":{"0":"0.032220032460810885"},"roic":{"0":"0.20313585674458502"},"roic_rank":{"0":2.0},"ey_rank":{"0":1.0},"sum_rank":{"0":3.0}},"1":{"company":{"1":"Microsoft Corporation"},"earnings_yield":{"1":"0.0360941393518613"},"roic":{"1":"0.1955875358727057"},"roic_rank":{"1":1.0},"ey_rank":{"1":2.0},"sum_rank":{"1":3.0}}}'
```

Comment: Can you explain how this works? Ideally I want the order to be based on sum_rank. Your lambda sorts it by index in the table? So even if I run any `df = df.sort_values(by='sum_rank')` or whatever. The index will remain the same - not sure if this solves my issue

Comment: Oh ok
For that you can set the index of df as sum_rank and then apply groupby on it.

        `df = df.set_index('sum_rank')`
        `json = df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x.to_dict(orient='records'))`
        `json = json.to_json()`

Comment: For groupby reference please see (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64574584/sending-a-sorted-table-from-pandas-dataframe-to-frontend/64575123#64575123)